# Проблема с сохранением конфигурационного файла ngrok

Tags: windows

У меня возникла проблема с сохранением файла с токеном.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подозреваю то что это из за русских букв в пути к файлу. Можно как то изменить пусть сохранения? Есть ли возможность переименовать имя отображения пользователей? Много где искал где поменять но в итоге только 1 учётная запись admin.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, сам не разобрался. Нужно дать права на папку с пользователем

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).